# Get config data in Yaml (bespoke variables) in any Symfony2 controller

Tags: symfony

I want to do this in the main app/config/config.yml file:

```
variables:
    a: 1
    email: jim@email.com
    variable2: hello
```

And this in any controller:

```
$variables = **get Yaml config data**
echo $variables['email'];
```

Of course I can't, but is anything like this possible?

I've seen where you can set global variables for access by Twig, but not seen how a Symfony2 controller can get them.

Of course if there's a better method as well then please mention that as this to me seems a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parameters` in `parameters.yml` for that:

```
parameters:
    email: boss@acme.com
```

This way you'll be able to get it in a controller this way:

```
$email = $this->container->getParameter('email');
```

You can also create a Twig global in `config.yml` to have access to it from Twig using the same parameter:

```
twig:
    globals:
        email: %email%
```

And in Twig:

```
{{ email }}
```